# Merge two api responses into one using Webclient - Webflux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using WebFlux and WebClient and I need to consume two APIs and merge its responses.

The first API receive type and document number and returns a list with one element that contains customer data (that's how it's defined).

The second API receive a client id and returns a customer payments list.

I need to consume these two APIs and return an entity with the customer data and their payments.

**API Customer response**

```
public class CustomerResponseApi {
    private List<CustomerApi> clientList;
}
```

```
public class CustomerApi {
    private int customerId;
    private String documentNumber;
    private String documentType;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

---

**API Payment Response**

```
public class PaymentResponseApi {
    private int customerId;
    private LocalDate paymentDate;
    private float amount;
    private String paymentType;
}
```

---

finally I should have this

**CustomerResponse.java**

```
public class CustomerResponse {
    private int customerId;
    private String documentNumber;
    private String documentType;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    private List<PaymentResponseApi> payments;
}
```

---

I have a proxy class that is responsible for making the API call

**CustomerProxy.java**

```
public class CustomerProxy {

    @Value("${api.base-url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    public Mono<CustomerResponseApi> getCustomer(String documentType, String documentNumber) {
        log.info("baseUrl: {}", baseUrl);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uri -> uri
                        .path("/customers")
                        .queryParam("documentNumber", documentNumber)
                        .queryParam("documentType", documentType)
                        .build()
                )
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CustomerResponseApi.class);
    }
}
```

**PaymentProxy.java**

```
public class PaymentProxy {

    @Value("${api.base-url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    public Flux<PaymentResponseApi> getCustomerPayment(int customerId) {
        log.info("baseUrl: {}", baseUrl);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uri -> uri
                        .path("/payments")
                        .queryParam("customerId", customerId)
                        .build()
                )
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(PaymentResponseApi.class);
    }
}
```

---

And a service that is responsible for merge responses
**CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerProxy customerProxy;
    
    @Autowired
    private PaymentProxy paymentProxy;

    @Override
    public Mono<CustomerResponse> getCustomerAndPayments(String documentType, String documentNumber) {
        return customerProxy.getCustomer(documentType, documentNumber).flatMap(resp -> {
            CustomerApi customerApi = resp.getClientList().get(0); //always returns one customer
            
            // Here is my problem, because getCustomerPayment method returns a Flux
            List<PaymentResponseApi> payments = paymentProxy.getCustomerPayment(customerApi.getCustomerId());
            
            CustomerResponseBuilder customerBuilder = CustomerResponse.builder()
                    .customerId(customerApi.getCustomerId())
                    .documentNumber(customerApi.getDocumentNumber())
                    .documentType(customerApi.getDocumentType())
                    .firstName(customerApi.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(customerApi.getLastName())
                    .payments(payments);
            
            return Mono.just(customerBuilder.build());
        });
    }
}
```

---

What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to resolve this:

1. Using nested maps:

```
public Mono<CustomerResponse> getCustomerAndPayments(String documentType, String documentNumber) {

    return customerProxy.getCustomer(documentType, documentNumber)
        .map(resp -> resp.getClientList().get(0))
        .flatMap(customerApi -> {
          Flux<PaymentResponseApi> paymentProxyFlux = paymentProxy.getCustomerPayment(customerApi.getCustomerId());
          return paymentProxyFlux.collectList()
              .map(payments -> {
                CustomerResponseBuilder customerBuilder = CustomerResponse.builder()
                    .customerId(customerApi.getCustomerId())
                    .documentNumber(customerApi.getDocumentNumber())
                    .documentType(customerApi.getDocumentType())
                    .firstName(customerApi.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(customerApi.getLastName())
                    .payments(payments);
                return customerBuilder.build();
              });
        });


  }
```

2. Using zip: **Since you need info from the response of first API in your second API, you need to chain these two together.** Now since they are async calls, you need a flatMap or a variant of flatMap called **flatMapMany** which emits more than one elements (which exactly what your 2nd API is doing). Next, you need both the responses to build your *CustomerResponse* i.e you need to **zip** the two reactive stream responses from the two APIs.

Thus basically using Method2 you need this:

```
  public Mono<CustomerResponse> getCustomerAndPayments(String documentType, String documentNumber) {


    Mono<CustomerApi> customerApiMono =  customerProxy.getCustomer(documentType, documentNumber)
        .map(resp -> resp.getClientList().get(0));
    Mono<List<PaymentResponseApi>> paymentResponseApiListMono = customerApiMono
        .flatMapMany(customerApi -> paymentProxy.getCustomerPayment(customerApi.getCustomerId()))
        .collectList();

    return customerApiMono.zipWith(paymentResponseApiListMono)
        .map(tuple -> {
          CustomerApi customerApi = tuple.getT1();
          List<PaymentResponseApi> payments = tuple.getT2();
          CustomerResponseBuilder customerBuilder = CustomerResponse.builder()
              .customerId(customerApi.getCustomerId())
              .documentNumber(customerApi.getDocumentNumber())
              .documentType(customerApi.getDocumentType())
              .firstName(customerApi.getFirstName())
              .lastName(customerApi.getLastName())
              .payments(payments);
          return customerBuilder.build();
        });

  }
```

Demerit of Method2: Api1 i.e customer API will be be subscribed twice.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty you can use Mono.zip(..) and pass two tuples.

Comment: @global_warming how does that make any difference ?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty customerApi won't be subscribed twice in that case, I think using Mono.zip with combinator can be used to return Mono<CustomerResponse> as that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can cache a result from the first call to prevent calling API twice.

Sometimes is also easier to work with `zip` operator by creating a wrapper class to not work on tuple. In this case `CustomerWithPayments` :

```
public class CustomerWithPayments {
    private final CustomerApi customerApi;
    private final List<PaymentResponseApi> paymentResponseApis;
}
```

Solution with caching the API result:

```
public Mono<CustomerResponse> getCustomerAndPayments(String documentType, String documentNumber) {
    Mono<CustomerApi> customerMono = customerProxy.getCustomer(documentType, documentNumber)
            .map(resp -> resp.getClientList().get(0))
            .cache();
    Mono<List<PaymentResponseApi>> paymentResponseMono = customerMono.map(CustomerApi::getCustomerId)
            .flatMapMany(paymentProxy::getCustomerPayment)
            .collectList();

    return customerMono.zipWith(paymentResponseMono, CustomerWithPayments::new)
            .map(customerWithPayments -> {
                CustomerApi customer = customerWithPayments.getCustomerApi();
                List<PaymentResponseApi> payments = customerWithPayments.getPaymentResponseApis();
                return CustomerResponse.builder()
                        .customerId(customer.getCustomerId())
                        .documentNumber(customer.getDocumentNumber())
                        .documentType(customer.getDocumentType())
                        .firstName(customer.getFirstName())
                        .lastName(customer.getLastName())
                        .payments(payments)
                        .build();
            });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this prevents calling CustomerApi twice? have u checked putting log?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty yup, I am sure